# How do I make the first option in a drop down list an unacceptable answer?

Tags: php, html, selection, required-field

Okay so I have a form and within this form are a bunch of required fields.  The birthday part of this form consists of 3 fields: month, day, and year.
Now what I want to do is have the words "Month:", "Day:", and "Year:" at the top of the drop down lists, BUT I do not want these options to be acceptable answers! When I submit the form without selecting an actual month, day, and year, it should say that the month, day, and year are required when I print the errors! How can I accomplish that?
My "if statements" that make the fields required are at the bottom of this code:

```
<form action="" method="post">  
        <ul id="register">
            <li>
                Birthday:

                <select name="month">
                    <option value="month">Month:</option>
                    <option value="January">January</option>
                    //all the other months
                </select>

                <select name="day">
                    <option value="day">Day:</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    //all the other days of the month
                </select>

                <select name="year">
                    <option value="year">Year:</option>
                    <option value="2013">2013</option>
                    //more year options
                </select><br><br>
            </li>

            <li>
                <input type="submit" name="registrationform" value="Sign up">
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
    <?php
    if (!empty($_POST['registrationform'])) {
    if(isset($_POST['registrationform'])){
        $required_fields = array('month', 'day', 'year');
        foreach ( $required_fields as $key=>$value) {
         if (!isset($_POST[$value]) || $_POST[$value]=='') {
              $errors[$value] = $key." is required";

            }
   }

   print_r($errors);
}
    }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use optgroup

```
<select name="month">
  <optgroup label="Month:">
    <option value="January">January</option>
    //all the other months
  </optgroup>
</select>

etc.
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5VJKE/)

or disable the option and select the title if you want the title to show - once the list is touched, the title will not be selectable.

```
<select name="month">
    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Month:</option>
    <option value="January">January</option>
    //all the other months
</select>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5VJKE/3/)

[image]

Comment: The optgroup option wasn't what I wanted because "January" is still the first thing I see before clicking the arrow to drop down the whole list of months.  The optgroup option just put the word "month" at the top of the list in bold.
I'll try the disable option right now and let you know if that works.
Thank you for taking the time to answer!

Comment: Just click on the Fiddle and you'll see the disabled is what you need.

Comment: The disable option did the exact same thing as the optgroup option except this time it just wasn't in bold.

Comment: Did you add selected="selected" - see screenshot above from the fiddle

Comment: No I did not, but I just did it right now and IT WORKED!!!
Thank you! I love when the answers are simple lol

Answer (score 1):

I agree with PassKit but please add some validation to your code

```
if (!is_int($_POST[$value])) {
  // not valid
}
```

And dont post months as January but as 1 .. 12 since it much safer and easier to validate

Comment: Thank you Passkit but what exactly does this code your recommending do?
I'm a beginner, so if you could explain that would be REALLY helpful!
And what exactly would I put in that //not valid part?

Oh and why do you say that it's safer to use 1 through 12?
I'll take your word for it and change my values right now but I just want to understand why.

Comment: in the // section add error handling. array_push($aErrors,'not a valid month'); And not checking your data makes you vulnerable to all sorts of funs tuf . Try this curl --data "month=<script>alert('hi')</script>" http://localhost/yourscript.php on your old code

Answer (score 1):

Give it an empty/no value and validate it

Comment: Can you explain how to do that?
Sorry, I just started coding a week ago and I've been learning as I go...